# Best first 100 career starts by quarterbacks

Tags: american-football, trivia, history, nfl, statistics

Few weeks ago Aaron Rodgers of the Green Bay Packers played his 100th career start, and with a win, he improved to 68-32; tying Brett Favre.

What are the top records for the first 100 career starts by a quarterback in the NFL?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Patriots.com](http://www.patriots.com/team/roster/tom-brady/272d4f2c-1bb9-4372-b02c-dfa3fa60575b/), the best record for a QB in his first 100 regular season starts during the Super Bowl era is 76-24, shared by Tom Brady and Roger Staubach:

> Brady won 76 of his first 100 regular season starts, tying Roger Staubach’s mark for most victories by a quarterback in his first 100 starts during the Super Bowl Era (since 1966).

The only other data I could find is for **active** QBs as of October 18, 2013 (source: [ESPN](http://espn.go.com/dallas/nfl/story/_/id/9835748/dallas-cowboys-tony-romo-deserves-more-credit-makes-100th-career-nfl-start?src=mobile&rand=ref~%7B%22ref%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F%22%7D)):

[image]

The reason you don't see Aaron Rodgers in that list is because he didn't start his 100th regular season game until this 2014 season.  The reason you don't see Brett Favre in that list is because he wasn't active in 2013 (he retired after the 2010 season).